# what is r-squared in linear regression models?

Tags: r, regression, dataset

I am a bit confused about the definition of the r-squared score in the linear regression model. As far as I know, the R-squared score represents how much of the dependent variable can be determined by the independent variables. However, in the scikit learn library, we have an r2-score function that calculates the r-squared score like r2_score(y_true, y_pred). But both of the parameters here are the output values, and it doesn't seem that it involves any of the indepent variables. Could you help me to understand how this is calculated?

Answer (score 1):

That y_pred is determined by your regression equation, which is determined by your predictor (independent) variables, such as by $y_{pred}=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ in an ordinary least squares linear regression (or some other function of the features in another model). This $y_{pred}$ usually is written as $\hat{y}$, as it is an estimate of $y$.

Since $\hat y$ is determined by the independent variables, I would consider the function to involve both dependent and independent variables.